# 'add to home screen' not available on android chrome

Tags: reactjs

Normally, when i am on any site  within android chrome and open the chrome menu there is an 'add to home screen' option. But when i open my react app there is only an 'install app' entry instead. How can i modify my project to enable normal links for home screens?
I am using Hashrouter inside my app if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome sees your app as a PWA (Progressive Web App), which can be installed locally. The "Add to home screen" option is probably disabled because Chrome assumes that a PWA is more likely to be installed than to just be referenced to.

I don't think there is any direct way to prevent Chrome from seeing your app as a PWA, other than modifying the `manifest.json` file to not include some of the requirements Chrome has for PWA's (https://web.dev/articles/install-criteria#criteria)

Comment: Thanks it worked. One has to remove the 'start_url' tag, other wise the links will all open the specified page.